# Trying to apply setInterval in my clock unsuccessfully

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I teaching myself JavaScript and trying to code something everyday. I'm currently trying to build a simple clock, but I' can't seem to get my setInterval to work. I've tried positioning it in different places, but I think it belongs to the 'time' function so should be positioned after that. I'm wondering if it has something to do with how I am invoking the functions. I'm not completely clear on the when to invoke by which method yet. Guidance would sure be appreciated.

```js
var dayTime = function() {
  // Create a new instance of the Date contructor function. 
  var date = new Date();

  var today = function() {
    // Create an array of weekday names
    var dayArray = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    // Extract the day. Will return a numeric representation.
    var dayIndex = date.getDay();

    // Step 4: Use weekday names array with weekday numeric to display text version of weekday.
    var today = dayArray[dayIndex];
    // Step 5: Place results into span on webpage
    var x = document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = today;
  }()

  var time = function() {

    var hours = date.getHours();
    var minutes = date.getMinutes();
    var seconds = date.getSeconds();
    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    // Set am or pm
    var amPm = hours < 12 ? "am" : "pm";

    // Set to 12 hour time format
    hours = hours > 12 ? hours - 12 : hours;

    // Convert midnight until 1am to 12
    hours = (hours == 0) ? 12 : hours;

    var y = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Current time is " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + amPm;

  }()
  setInterval(time, 1000);
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body onload="dayTime();">
  <h1>Simple Date Exercise</h1>
  <p>Today is <span id="day"></span>
  </p>
  <p id="time">00:00</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `time` is undefined, since you're calling the function immediately.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> setInterval(time, 1000);
> ```

The first argument of `setInterval` needs to be a function. You are passing the `time` variable which contains …

> ```
> var time = function() {
>     // A bunch of statements but no return statement
> }()
> ```

Since you follow it with `()`, you are calling it immediately, so the return value (`undefined`) is assigned to `time`.

---

Remove the `()`. Don't call the function immediately.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I have to process this and practice, but it looks like what I need .

Answer (score 0):

You can call `dayTime()` with `setInterval()` instead, and have a straight call to `time()`. Also, I'd set an interval lower than a second, to make sure it updates a bit more accurately to the second.

```js
var dayTime = function() {
      // Create a new instance of the Date contructor function. 
      var date = new Date();
    
      var today = function() {
        // Create an array of weekday names
        var dayArray = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
        // Extract the day. Will return a numeric representation.
        var dayIndex = date.getDay();
    
        // Step 4: Use weekday names array with weekday numeric to display text version of weekday.
        var today = dayArray[dayIndex];
        // Step 5: Place results into span on webpage
        var x = document.getElementById("day").innerHTML = today;
      }()
    
      var time = function() {
    
        var hours = date.getHours();
        var minutes = date.getMinutes();
        var seconds = date.getSeconds();
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
    
        // Set am or pm
        var amPm = hours < 12 ? "am" : "pm";
    
        // Set to 12 hour time format
        hours = hours > 12 ? hours - 12 : hours;
    
        // Convert midnight until 1am to 12
        hours = (hours == 0) ? 12 : hours;
    
        var y = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = "Current time is " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds + " " + amPm;
    
      }();
    };
    setInterval(dayTime, 500);
```

```html
  <h1>Simple Date Exercise</h1>
  <p>Today is <span id="day"></span>
  </p>
  <p id="time">00:00</p>
```

Comment: That works. I did this and have it working, although I still need to spend more time to fully appreciate why it's working! I have also adjusted the interval length. Appreciate the help.